# I have enabled flat categories, and after doing this some of my categories are not showing there related products?

Tags: flat-catalog

I have enabled flat categories, and after doing this some of my categories are not showing there related products, infact when i click to the specific category it redirects me to the same page (category listing)? Is there anything which i can do for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reindexing?

```
Admin > System > Index Management
```

Choose "Select All" and click "Submit"

---

Alternatively, you can use SSH to trigger this as well:

```
/usr/local/bin/php shell/indexer.php reindexall

/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Both of those commands can be run from the root of your Magento install.

---

You can reset your file & folder permissions with these commands from the /magento root.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod 550 mage
chmod -R o+w media
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried re-indexing from admin and ssh as well. Same result.

Comment: have you cleared cookies and cache on your browser? tried incognito/private mode? You should also check and reset your permissions. I have added those steps to the original answer.